Saving edited PDFs directly to application from QuickLook
I'm stuck on a problem where I need to be able to have the same editing capabilities as in .quickLookPreview and be able to save the edited file to the application with the "Done" button.
So, in nutshell, I need to implement the same functionality many other applications provide including Apple's Files.
However with .quickLookPreview I don't get the ability to save edited files directly to the application, and I've had no luck finding help from the internet (thus this question).
Perhaps somebody has implemented this before and could give me a lead somewhere?
PS. I'm trying to find a solution without any third party libraries

It appears this question's gotten -2 points, would someone like to give me a reason why so I could fix it in the post?

This is not available for now in the SwiftUI Quick Look API, but is available with the UIKit version, QLPreviewController.
